# Create long data format based on strings of sequences defined by colons and concatenated vectors

Tags: r, string, tidyr, sequences, tidyverse

I have data where the IDs of each observation are numbers stored as sequences usually in the form of X:Y, but sometimes concatenated lists. I would like to tidy the data so each observation has its own row so that I can then use a join function to add more descriptive IDs. Normally I'd use the `gather()` function from `tidyr` to do this but I'm having trouble unpacking the IDs as they are characters.

The data looks like this:

```
example <- data_frame(x = LETTERS[1:3], y = c("Condition 1", "Condition 2", "Condition 3"), z = c("1:3", "4:6", "c(7,9,10)"))

example
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      x           y         z
  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>
1     A Condition 1       1:3
2     B Condition 2       4:6
3     C Condition 3 c(7,9,10)
```

However these do not work and all produce `NA`:

```
as.numeric("1:3")
as.integer("1:3")
as.numeric("c(7,9,10)")
as.integer("c(7,9,10)")
```

There must be a simple way to do this but I thought one long way might be to extract the numbers and store them as a list first. For the X:Y IDs I could do this by spliting the string at ":" and then creating a sequence from one number to the other like so:

```
example[1:2,] %>% 
+   separate(z, c("a", "b"), sep = ":") %>% 
+   mutate(a = as.numeric(a), b = as.numeric(b), new = list(seq(a, b)))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 'from' must be of length 1
```

However this did not work.

What I'm aiming for looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
      x           y     z
  <chr>       <chr> <dbl>
1     A Condition 1     1
2     A Condition 1     2
3     A Condition 1     3
4     B Condition 2     4
5     B Condition 2     5
6     B Condition 2     6
7     C Condition 3     7
8     C Condition 3     9
9     C Condition 3    10
```

What is the simplest way of achieving it?

Comment: Unless you're extending the language, it's a bad idea to store code as strings. If you need to store more than one value per observation, use a list column.

Comment: I agree. This data format comes out of a 3rd party bioinformatics package. I might make a suggestion on their github repo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
example %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(z = list(eval(parse(text=z)))) %>%
    unnest
#      x           y     z
#   <chr>       <chr> <dbl>
#1     A Condition 1     1
#2     A Condition 1     2
#3     A Condition 1     3
#4     B Condition 2     4
#5     B Condition 2     5
#6     B Condition 2     6
#7     C Condition 3     7
#8     C Condition 3     9
#9     C Condition 3    10
```